# Is SQL Server Management Studio 17.1 compatible with SQL Server 2016 (Developer Edition)?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2016

I've installed **SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition**, because Microsoft states:

> SSDT database projects in Visual Studio 2017 currently support up to SQL Server 2016. Support for SQL Server 2017 will be coming soon in a Visual Studio 2017 update.

My question is: Should I install exclusively **SSMS 2016** or **SQL Server Management Studio 17.1** is compatible with **SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition** as well ?

Comment: it's compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @[scsimon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6167855/scsimon) for giving me an air of confidence.

I've installed **SSMS 2017.1**. It's compatible with **SQL Server 2016**, it works like a charm and, to be honest, it is much faster then **SSMS 2016**.